Exception when using Dynamic Lamda expression on a list-Attempting to JIT compile method in aot only mode
Hi I am in a migration of Xamarin.Ios project to net7.0. I am using the “net7.0-ios16.1” as the target framework. When I execute the below code, I am getting the exception.
"Attempting to JIT compile method '(wrapper delegate-invoke) bool <Module>:invoke_callvirt_bool_List`1<bool>_int (System.Collections.Generic.List`1<bool>,int)' while running in aot-only mode."

Please note that the below code is working in the simulator for both debug and release mode. But it is not working on the real device for both Release and Debug mode.
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Line, bool>>(expression, param);

var filterLines = new ObservableCollection<Line>(iQueryable.Where(lambda));

I have added the below code in the Project.cs page. But still the above crashing .
<PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-ios')) and '$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
      <UseInterpreter>true</UseInterpreter>
     <MtouchInterpreter>-all</MtouchInterpreter> 
</PropertyGroup>

Can anyone suggest a way to solve this issue.

Using  <UseInterpreter>true</UseInterpreter> is enough. You don't need to set both  of them. Does it still crash in iOS release mode? By the way, .NET7 is out of support. We recommend you use the latest .NET8.

Yes. I tried setting true setting alone. It is still getting crash in both debug and release when we deploy it in the real device. The problem is only in the real device. Simulator is working fine. I tried .Net8 also. Same issue in .Net 8.

<MtouchInterpreter>-all</MtouchInterpreter> means not to interpreter all assembilies. Do you want to use all instead of -all? By the way, could you please provide more relevant code to help us reproduce?

I have converted my app to .Net8 and suddently all worked well. I have then removed true and -all . its worked after removed the code also. I think update helped to solve the issue
